# Footer goes on top and I want it at the bottom

Tags: html, css

### I'm trying to setting up a template HTML / CSS / Javascript.

### My footer don't stay down.

As you can see if the page is full, **[like this](https://oiz.altervista.org/generic.html)** it works more or less good.

But if the page doesn't fills all the screen **[like this](https://oiz.altervista.org/generic1.html)** the footer goes up.

*If you don't have a good big screen resolution you don't see that. In this case push CTRL &
 minus to see the problem (or CMD & minus on MacOs).*

I love it and I want to use just that template.

I've tried also something that

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
}
```

but the footer had to follow the last section.

**It's possible to set it to stay at the end of the page maintaining the same layout?**

P.S. I prefer to do it only with CSS without using JS, because some browsers can't have it.

Thank U

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
bottom: 0
```

This should set the bottom edge of the element to the bottom edge of the parent element.

Comment: Natalie why talking without trying. I give you the code.. I can't vote down, but you deserve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques for doing this.

Once technique, which I sometimes use, is the flexbox sticky footer.

To achieve this, give the body the following css

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

You'll need to wrap the rest of your site content in a container. Perhaps, `<div class="site-content">` then give it the following CSS

```
.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Your footer will be placed beneath your .site-content `<div>`.

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on template link you provided.

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Blabla</p>
<div class="footer">©ikiK</div>
```

Comment: ikiK mmm... not working your Blabla with this tags. You tried only on one page [link](https://oiz.altervista.org/generic2.html) and not on the oher  [link](https://oiz.altervista.org/generic3.html). It covers the text. It will came after the section. Think that position fixed `left: 0 bottom: 0; width: 100%;` it's too much easy to works on this. thanks the same